# Second level retries is not working in NServiceBus when time out manager is disabled

Tags: delay, nservicebus

I'm using NServicebus 4.3.3 with SqlServer. I found out that there is a correlation between disabling the time out manager and the Second Level retry (SLR). Why is that ? Is there a way to make the SLR work without enabling the time out manager ? I'm not using a saga so there is no need for the time out manager and if I enable it my application does not start up anymore. It is hosted in IIS (express).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I had to disable the saga feature (Configure.Features.Disable();). Then I did not have to disable the timeout manager and the second level retries work

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce this by converting the ErrorHandling sample and in particular the one that uses SLR to use the SqlServer transport, and it works as expected for me.  I am not seeing what you are experiencing.

Its possible that I might be missing something. Can you please open an issue here with details on how to reproduce this issue?
https://github.com/particular/nservicebus.sqlserver/issues?state=open

I used NServiceBus version 4.3.4 and SqlServer 1.1.0 for my testing.

Comment: Thanks Indu I just also used the ErrorHandling example. The default version works but it does not make a connection with a db. So I added code that implements the IWantToRunBeforeConfiguration interface. There I put next line in the Init method :  Configure.With().DisableTimeoutManager(); I deleted all queues that are created before with running the default code. I run the changed code and then the SLR will throw a lot of errors. So I has something to do with the disabling of the timeoutmanager (which I need otherwise my application does not start up ) It is an ASP.net MVC hosted in IIS expr.

Comment: I found out that there is a correlation between disabletimeoutmanager and the second level retries. If the timeoutmanager is disabled the second level retries will not work. The queues for the slr are not created. This is how the people from NServiceBus has implement it. I do not need saga's. If I enable the timeoutmanager my asp.net mvc app does not start up anymore Seems to be that I have a problem with saga's and sql server Maybe you can tell me what could be the problem with this Indu ?